# Peculiar Rendered Output From Bold Math Font

Tags: math-mode, fonts, bold, boldmath

The bold math font is rendered in a very peculiar and ugly way, as you can see in the following image. To be more specific, you can see that the bold letters, w and x appear as if there is a shadow behind them. I tried alternative math fonts with the same result, so it is not font specific. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont
[%
  UprightFont = *,
  BoldFont = *Bold,
  ItalicFont = *It,
  BoldItalicFont = *BoldIt
]{GFSArtemisia.otf}

\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Text
%
\begin{equation}
    \pmb{w}^{t+1} = \pmb{w}^{t} + a\cdot f(\pmb{w}^{t}\cdot \pmb{x}^{t})\cdot \pmb{x}^{t}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have declared some bold fonts but you are using `\pmb` that is "poor man's bold" which simply over-prints three copies of the letter, offset slightly to give the appearance of bold when no bold font is available.

Use `\symbf` or `\mathbf` etc to get the bold characters from the math fonts.

Comment: The first command `\symbbf` produces an error but the second works great, what is the difference? Thank you very much though, really useful tip that I didn't know!

Comment: @Adam see the uniocde-math manual they are both defined (or re-defined) there. but basically `\symxxx` uses the math alphabets from the same font (Unicode math fonts have bold letters up in the U+1Dxxx codepoint range, whereas `\mathxxx` work as the similarly named commands in pdflatex, and select the same character from a different font (eg a bold font)

Comment: I will do that, nice explanation, thanks again.

Comment: @Mico one day I may learn to type

Answer (score 6):

David Carlisle is correct, but I think it would be useful to supplement his answer with an example of how to use Artemisia Bold Italic in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{GFSArtemisia.otf}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range=up,
             Script=Latin, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{GFS Artemisia Regular}
\setmathfont[range=it,
             Script=Latin, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{GFS Artemisia Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup,
             Script=Latin, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{GFS Artemisia Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit,
             Script=Latin, script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{GFS Artemisia Bold Italic}

\begin{document}

Text
%
\begin{equation}
    \symbfit{w}^{t+1} =
       \symbfit{w}^{t}
       + a \cdot f\left(\symbfit{w}^{t} \cdot \symbfit{x}^{t}\right)
           \cdot \symbfit{x}^{t}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Artemisia font sample]

The `mathastext` or `mathspec` packages would also work, with less boilerplate.  (You can at least remove the `Script`, `script-features` and `sscript-features` lines if you choose.  Their only purpose is to suppress harmless warning messages.)

I also removed a few packages that are redundant with `unicode-math`.  It loads `fontspec` and `amsmath` for you, and has its own `\boldmath`, `\mathbf` and `\symbf` commands that you should use instead of `bm`.

If you really need to fake a bold face for a font that does not have one, you can do that with the `fontspec` font option `[FakeBold=1.2]`, or whatever other number looks best.

Comment: Thanks that is a great answer!